# Density question on intersection of two spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Banach Spaces and $Z$ be a dense subset of $X$ and of $Y$, i.e., $\overline{(Z)}^{\|.\|_X} = X$ and  $\overline{(Z)}^{\|.\|_Y} = Y$.

Then can we say that $Z$ is dense in $(X \cap Y, \|.\|_{X \cap Y})$, where $\|.\|_{X \cap Y}$ is any norm (to be specific either max norm or "$\|.\|_X + \|.\|_Y$" norm)?

Comment: Ah, you were right about the need of one sequence over two norms. So my answer was incorrect. I'll think about how to fix that once I have some time.

Comment: Are the underlaying set of the spaces $X$ and $Y$ the same?

Comment: As sets $X$ and $Y$ are same but with norm they are different.

Comment: It seems the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3011468/dense-subset-of-two-banach-spaces-also-dense-in-the-intersection